# count words present in grid

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a grid of characters, and array of strings, find if the word is present in the grid.
To find the word, we can pick any cell and move from left to right, or top to bottom.
We have a special case, we can change directions at most once, it means if we are moving from left to right, we can go down to find the word existence in the grid.

**Example**

```
Grid :
["c", "o", "d", "g"],
["a", "t", "e", "r"],
["z", "o", "p", "s"]]

words = ["code", "coder", "cat", "top", "spot"]
```

**Result:** `Count how many words are present in grid = 3`

**Explanation:**

```
string "code" is valid and its path is [0][0]-> [0][1] -> [0][2] →[1][2] Here, First it goes from left to right, then it changes direction once by going from top to bottom at [0][2]

string "coder" is not valid because we need to change the direction two times to find its existence in input grid.

string "cat" is valid and its path is [0][0] -> [1][0]-> [1][1].

string "top" is valid and its path [1][1] -> [2][1] -> [2][2].

string "spot" is not valid because its path is from right to left and bottom to top.

So valid strings are code, cat, top so result is 3.
```

I tried to solve this, I am able to search row wise and column wise but I am stuck at changing the direction at most once.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean wordExists(char[][] matrix, String word) {
    // Check each row
    for (char[] row : matrix) {
        if (checkRow(row, word)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Check each column
    for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
        char[] column = new char[matrix.length];
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            column[row] = matrix[row][col];
        }
        if (checkRow(column, word)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static boolean checkRow(char[] row, String word) {
    int charIndex = 0;
    for (char c : row) {
        if (c == word.charAt(charIndex)) {
            charIndex++;
            if (charIndex == word.length()) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            charIndex = 0; // Start over if character mismatch
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'd separate out`checkColumn()` into its own function and modify both so that they take in four arguments: the matrix, a position (row and column) into the matrix, the word itself (which you do), and a flag stating if direction may be changed or not. Doing this should allow you to keep your existing logic while requiring only a few changes to handle for directional changes.

Comment: You need to check for the next character in all 4 directions {1,1}, {1,-1}, {-1,1} and {-1,-1}. And then apply the same logic on each of those characters that is true till you either find the word or go out of bound.
This is a classic WordSearch Problem. Can be implemented by using recursive stack or a trie-tree.

Comment: Can you also move in the complete OPPOSITE direction? For instance, is the word `tater` allowed?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, not allowed. We can move only from left to right and top to bottom. With one additional change allowed, means if we are going from left to right, we can go down to find the word.

Comment: @AmolGharpure, all 4 directions is not allowed for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick example. I hope it helps you.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    private static char [][] grid = 
        { 
            {'c', 'o', 'd', 'g'}, 
            {'a', 't', 'e', 'r'}, 
            {'z', 'o', 'p', 's'} 
        };
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        

        String [] words = {"code", "coder", "cat", "top", "spot"};
        int count = 0;
        
        for (String word : words) {
            // For each word ...
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    // ... search for the first character
                    if (word.charAt(0) == grid[i][j]) {
                        // If first character was found ... 
                        // ... check the line for others characters from the startI e startJ position. 
                        if (findWordLine(word, 1, i, j, true)) {
                            // If found increment count variable
                            count++;
                        } 
                        
                        // ... check the line for others characters from the startI e startJ position.
                        if (findWordColumn(word, 1, i, j, true)) {
                            // If found increment count variable
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Count how many words are present in grid = " + count);
    }
    
    private static boolean findWordLine(String word, int nextCharacter, int startI, int startJ, boolean canChange) { 
        int i = startI, j = startJ;
        
        // From the start point startI and startJ check if "nextCharacter" char is equal to the grid position (j + 1)
        while(nextCharacter < word.length()) {
            if ((j + 1) < 4 && word.charAt(nextCharacter) == grid[i][j + 1]) {
                // If is equal increment j and nextCharacter variables
                j++;
                nextCharacter++;
            }
            else if (canChange && (i + 1) < 3 && word.charAt(nextCharacter) == grid[i + 1][j])
                // If next char in the line is not equal but the char in (i+1) is, the method is used findWordColumn passing canChange = false because only one change of direction can be made
                return findWordColumn(word, nextCharacter, i, j, false);
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
        
    private static boolean findWordColumn(String word, int nextCharacter, int startI, int startJ, boolean canChange) { 
        int i = startI, j = startJ;
        
        // From the start point startI and startJ check if "nextCharacter" char is equal to the grid position (i + 1)
        while(nextCharacter < word.length()) {
            if ((i + 1) < 3 && word.charAt(nextCharacter) == grid[i + 1][j]) {
                // If is equal increment i and nextCharacter variables
                i++;
                nextCharacter++;
            }
            else if (canChange && (j + 1) < 4 && word.charAt(nextCharacter) == grid[i][j + 1])
                // If next char in the column is not equal but the char in (j+1) is, the method is used findWordLine passing canChange = false because only one change of direction can be made
                return findWordLine(word, nextCharacter, i, j, false);
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add explanation also for this code

Comment: Now I realized there's a issue in this code. I'll try to fix it and put some explanation as soon as possible.

Comment: I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I denote by **turning point** the point where you change the direction.

Initially, I imagined the solution the following way: I would pick a **starting point** (any point in the grid), then pick a turning point in the remaining part of the grid, to the right and bottom of the starting point.
Next, I would join the starting point with the turning point, change the direction, of course, and continue until I reach the boundary of the grid.
Within the obtained string, I would check if the desired word is a prefix.

Later, I realized that I can omit the starting point. So, within two for loops, I pick any point as a candidate for a turning point. Then, from that turning point, I go both in the vertical and the horizontal directions, until I reach the boundaries of the grid. Note that there are two ways of doing this - from the turning point I could go west and south, or north and east, so to say.  Joining these two segments, a vertical one and a horizontal one, would form an L shape. Now, any word you might look for is a substring of one such L shape (L shape have their ends on the boundaries of the grid). Please note that straight lines are particular cases of these L shapes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862171/count-words-present-in-grid

public class Main {
    
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 4;
    String[][] grid = {{"c", "o", "d", "g"},
                       {"a", "t", "e", "r"},
                       {"z", "o", "p", "s"}};

    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        
        //print code below to test that methods joinedSegments.. work properly
        /*
        for(int i=0;i<m.rows;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<m.cols; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("("+i+","+j+")");
                System.out.println(m.joinedSegmentsHorizontalFirst(i, j, m.grid, m.rows, m.cols));
                System.out.println(m.joinedSegmentsVerticalFirst(i, j, m.grid, m.rows, m.cols));
            }
        } */
        
        ArrayList<String> allWordWrappers = m.allWordWrappers(m.grid, m.rows, m.cols);
        
        System.out.println(m.findWord("code", allWordWrappers));
        System.out.println(m.findWord("coder", allWordWrappers));
        System.out.println(m.findWord("cat", allWordWrappers));
        System.out.println(m.findWord("top", allWordWrappers));
        System.out.println(m.findWord("spot", allWordWrappers));

    }
    
    /*remember that the word you are looking for needs only to be a substring of the L-shaped form 
     * whose ends touch the boundaries of the grid*/
    boolean findWord(String word, ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(list.get(i).contains(word))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    /*
     * for every point (i,j) in the grid, we call both joinedSegmentsHorizontalFirst and joinedSegmentsVerticalFirst;
     * and we store these strings; Any of the words you are looking for (words that can have one turning point, or none), 
     * are contained in such strings that span from one boundary of the grid, to the adjacent (not the opposite) boundary of the 
     * grid; like, for example, from the left border to the bottom border
     * also remember that straight lines are also included, being just particular cases of the L-shaped forms
     * */
    ArrayList<String> allWordWrappers (String[][] grid, int gridRows, int gridCols) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for(int i=0; i< gridRows; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j< gridCols; j++)
            {
                list.add(joinedSegmentsHorizontalFirst(i, j, grid, gridRows, gridCols));
                list.add(joinedSegmentsVerticalFirst(i, j, grid, gridRows, gridCols));
            }
        }
        
        return list;
    }
    
    /*given a turning point, described by its row and column (rowtp and coltp), 
     * the result is the string obtained by joining segment (rowtp,0) to (rowtp, coltp) with  
     * segment (rowtp,coltp) to (max_row, coltp) 
     * basically, it is an L -shaped form, whose ends touch the grid's boundaries, and has 
     * in its middle the turning point which was given as a parameter
     * 
     * in fact, there are two such L forms that are acceptable: one that starts horizontally, and ends vertically, 
     * and one that starts vertically and ends horizontally; hence the two different methods
     * 
     * what about straight lines? these are particular cases, when the turning point is found on the 
     * boundary of the grid
     * */
    public String joinedSegmentsHorizontalFirst(int rowtp, int coltp, String[][] grid, int gridRows, int gridCols) throws Exception
    {
        String first = gridSlice(rowtp,0,rowtp,coltp, grid, gridRows, gridCols);
        String second = gridSlice(rowtp, coltp, gridRows-1, coltp, grid, gridRows, gridCols);
        
        /*if we simply concatenate first+second, we would have the point (rowtp,coltp) twice*/
        
        return (first.substring(0, first.length()-1))+second;
    }
    
    public String joinedSegmentsVerticalFirst(int rowtp, int coltp, String[][] grid, int gridRows, int gridCols) throws Exception
    {
        String first = gridSlice(0, coltp, rowtp, coltp, grid, gridRows, gridCols);
        String second = gridSlice(rowtp, coltp, rowtp, gridCols-1, grid, gridRows, gridCols);
        //again, we need to take into account only once the letter at (rowtp, coltp)
        
        return (first.substring(0, first.length()-1))+second;
    }
    
    /*returning all the elements in the grid, from a starting point, to an ending point, including both 
     * start and end; the start and end points have got to be on either same column or same row */
    public String gridSlice(int rowStart, int colStart, int rowEnd, int colEnd, String[][] grid, int gridRows, int gridCols) throws Exception
    {
        String result = "";
        
        if(rowStart >= gridRows || rowEnd >= gridRows || colStart >= gridCols || colEnd >= gridCols)
        {
            throw new Exception("wrong parameters - row or column index outside of grid borders");
        }
        
        if(rowStart != rowEnd && colStart != colEnd)
        {
            throw new Exception("start and end point have got to be on either same line or same column");
        }
        
        if(rowStart == rowEnd)
        {
            for(int i=colStart; i<= colEnd; i++)
            {
                result = result + grid[rowStart][i];
            }
        }
        
        /*if(colStart == colEnd)*/  /*don't uncomment this line; it is equivalent to the "else" below, 
        unless both starting and ending point are identical; in this case, both loops execute */
        else
        {
            for(int j=rowStart; j<= rowEnd; j++)
            {
                result = result + grid[j][colStart];
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    
    
}
```